# AngularJS Directive Countup.JS get data from model

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using this plugin: [COUNTUP](https://github.com/inorganik/countUp.js/blob/master/dist/countUp.js)

and I have the following directive:

```
directive('upCounter', function () {

    return {
        restrict: 'EAC',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
            var $el = angular.element(el),
                sm = scrollMonitor.create(el);

            sm.fullyEnterViewport(function () {
                var opts = {
                    useEasing: attrDefault($el, 'easing', true),
                    useGrouping: attrDefault($el, 'grouping', true),
                    separator: attrDefault($el, 'separator', ','),
                    decimal: attrDefault($el, 'decimal', '.'),
                    prefix: attrDefault($el, 'prefix', ''),
                    suffix: attrDefault($el, 'suffix', '')
                },
                $count = attrDefault($el, 'count', 'this') == 'this' ? $el : $el.find($el.data('count')),
                from = attrDefault($el, 'from', 0),
                to = attrDefault($el, 'ng-model', 100),
                duration = attrDefault($el, 'duration', 2.5),
                delay = attrDefault($el, 'delay', 0),
                decimals = new String(to).match(/\.([0-9]+)/) ? new String(to).match(/\.([0-9]+)$/)[1].length : 0,
                counter = new countUp($count.get(0), from, to, decimals, duration, opts);

                setTimeout(function () { counter.start(); }, delay * 1000);

                sm.destroy();
            });
        }
    };
}).
```

How can I change the directive so that I can pass a `data-ng-model` value for the `to` parameter?

EDIT:

I've tried adding `scope:{ ngModel: '='}` but I got this error:

Error: $compile:multidir 
Multiple Directive Resource Contention

Multiple directives [upCounterupCounter, new/isolated scope] asking for {4} on: {5}

Description

This error occurs when multiple directives are applied to the same DOM element, and processing them would result in a collision or an unsupported configuration.

To resolve this issue remove one of the directives which is causing the collision.

Example scenarios of multiple incompatible directives applied to the same element include:

- Multiple directives requesting isolated scope.
- Multiple directives publishing a controller under the same name.
- Multiple directives declared with the transclusion option.
- Multiple directives attempting to define a template or templateURL.

Comment: You can use `require: 'ngModel'` then in your link function pass ngModel as the 4th argument.  This will allow you to access the ngModel API in your link function.  ngModel.$viewValue gives you access to the current value.  Will try and mock up an example demo for you if you need it.

Comment: Thanks for your information. I actually did tried it like you mentioned but within the directive the value of ` ngModel.$viewValue` is `Nan`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that you probably aren't using a $watch to wait for the value to be initialized after the first digest. If you take a look at the ngModel directive source, you'll see that the ngModelController initializes the $viewValue as NaN.

So, adding a $watch will do the trick:

```js
var app = angular.module('countup.demo', []);
app.controller('CounterCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.countervalue = 100;
}])
.directive('upCounter', function () {

  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
      scope.$watch(ngModel, function(newval) {
        alert(ngModel.$viewValue);
      });
      
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.16/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="countup.demo">
  <div ng-controller="CounterCtrl">
    <div up-counter id="counter" ng-model="countervalue"></div>
    <p>countervalue: {{countervalue}}</p>
  </div>
</div>
```